# Unique visitors in antonioribeiro/tracker laravel package

Tags: php, laravel

I am using [antonioribeiro/tracker](https://github.com/antonioribeiro/tracker) laravel package to store user tracker information.

In this package there are many useful method to get information. for example there is a `sessions()` method to get all visits on past day:

```
$todayVisits   = Tracker::sessions(60 * 24)->count();
```

But I do not know how can I get Unique visitors of past day.

Of course there is a `users()` method that return count of registered users that visit pages:

```
$todayVisitors = Tracker::users(60 * 24)->count();
```

But I want to count visit of guest users that are not really registered.

How Can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In new released version antonio added [onlineUsers](https://github.com/antonioribeiro/tracker#online-users) to get users that are online:

```
$users = Tracker::onlineUsers();
```

In older version I used bellow code to that :

```
$onlineVisitors =
DB::table('tracker_sessions')->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subSeconds(30))->count();
```